# Expo TrackingTransparency failing when asking for permission

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I'm building an app for iOS using Expo and I require the use of the TrackingTransparency. For some reason when I ask for the user permission it fails with the following error:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ExpoTrackingTransparency.default.requestPermissionsAsync')]
at node_modules\expo-tracking-transparency\build\TrackingTransparency.js:31:7 in requestTrackingPermissionsAsync
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:293:29 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:154:27 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:189:16 in PromiseImpl$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:45:6 in tryCallTwo
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:200:22 in doResolve
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:66:11 in Promise
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:188:15 in callInvokeWithMethodAndArg
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:211:38 in enqueue
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:238:8 in exports.async
at node_modules\expo-tracking-transparency\build\TrackingTransparency.js:5:41 in <global>
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:293:29 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:154:27 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:189:16 in PromiseImpl$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:45:6 in tryCallTwo
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:200:22 in doResolve
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:66:11 in Promise
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:188:15 in callInvokeWithMethodAndArg
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:211:38 in enqueue
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:238:8 in exports.async
at node_modules\react-native-gradient-buttons\src\index.js:80:29 in <anonymous>
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Pressability\Pressability.js:691:17 in _performTransitionSideEffects
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Pressability\Pressability.js:628:6 in _receiveSignal
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Pressability\Pressability.js:524:8 in responderEventHandlers.onResponderRelease
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:265:4 in invokeGuardedCallbackImpl
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:476:2 in invokeGuardedCallback
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:500:2 in invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:597:41 in executeDispatch
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:621:19 in executeDispatchesInOrder
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2521:28 in executeDispatchesAndRelease
at [native code]:null in forEach
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:836:4 in forEachAccumulated
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2546:20 in runEventsInBatch
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2702:18 in runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2639:35 in batchedUpdates$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17712:13 in batchedUpdates$1
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2492:29 in batchedUpdates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2638:16 in _receiveRootNodeIDEvent
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2767:27 in receiveTouches
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

I installed the library as expo indicates [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v42.0.0/sdk/tracking-transparency/)

Also, after I installed the library in my app.json appeared as a plugin

```
"plugins": [
      "expo-tracking-transparency"
    ]
```

And when I start the app the log says:

```
Error: Problem validating fields in app.json. Learn more: https://docs.expo.io/workflow/configuration/
 • should NOT have additional property 'plugins'.
```

But I'm not sure if that's a real issue or I can ignore it.

The question is, what else can I do to make the tracking transparency library work?

My code where I'm requesting the permission is the following:

```
const logInHandler = () => {
        (async () => {
            const w = await requestTrackingPermissionsAsync();
            console.log(w);
            const { status } = await requestTrackingPermissionsAsync();
            if (status === 'granted') {
                login();
            } else {
                dispatchAlertState({
                    action: SHOW_ALERT,
                    message:
                        'Permission is required in order to log in.',
                    type: AlertType.error,
                });
            }
        })();
    };
```

[EDIT]

I noticed that if I use the `isAvailable()` method from the expo-tracking-transparency library it says that the TrackingTransparency API is not available on the device, which is weird, because the simulator is an iPad running iOS 14.5, I also tested on an iPad mini 2 which runs iOS 12.5 it says it is not available (as expected), but the expo docs say the `getTrackingPermissionsAsync()` should always return true on older devices and Android.

[Edit 2]
If someone reads this and has the same problem, make sure to be using the expo V42, I was using the V40 which does not contain the code to get the permission